# focus not working

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use JQuery's focus() method and I don't understand why it's not working. Here's a fiddle: [`jsfiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/E85pn/11/) any suggestions?

HTML Code

```
    <div class="documents-container cfx">
   <table class="documents-table">
      <tbody>
         <tr class="table-row-details" style="display: none;">
            <td class="pad-box-table-details" colspan="6">
               <div>
                  <h4> test </h4>
                  <ul class="styled-list">
                     <li> How to solve the issue... </li>
                     <li> Some other solution... </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="with-details js-toggle-table-details">
            <td>
               24.08.2015
               <div class="meta">
                  12:45
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               Sending despatch advice
            </td>
            <td>
               ... 
               <div class="meta">
                  test
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               <a href="#">
               Unknown receiver
               </a>
            </td>
            <td id="resolvedStatus">
               Unresolved 
            </td>
            <td class="align-right">
               <div id="infoBubble" class="js-info-bubble-parent">
                  <div class="document-status document-status--red js-docReqAttention-bubble-toggler">
                     <div class="js-info-bubble info-bubble info-bubble-bottom info-bubble-bottom-right" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="info-bubble-content">
                           <div class="document-status-bubble">
                              additional info to be added...
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="table-row-details" style="display: table-row;">
            <td class="pad-box-table-details" colspan="6">
               <div>
                  <ul class="styled-list">
                     <li> How to solve the issue... </li>
                     <li> Some other solution... </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="with-details js-toggle-table-details">
            <td>
               24.08.2015
               <div class="meta">
                  12:41
               </div>
            </td>
            <td>
               Sending despatch advice
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td>
               <a href="#">
               Unknown receiver
               </a>
            </td>
            <td id="resolvedStatus">
               Unresolved 
            </td>
            <td class="align-right">
               <div id="infoBubble" class="js-info-bubble-parent">
                  <div class="document-status document-status--red js-docReqAttention-bubble-toggler">
                     <div class="js-info-bubble info-bubble info-bubble-bottom info-bubble-bottom-right" style="display: none;">
                        <div class="info-bubble-content">
                           <div class="document-status-bubble">
                              additional info to be added...
                           </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr class="table-row-details" style="display: none;">
            <td class="pad-box-table-details" colspan="6">
               <div>
                  <ul class="styled-list">
                     <li> How to solve the issue... </li>
                     <li> Some other solution... </li>
                  </ul>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </tbody>
   </table>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
.documents-container {
    padding: 40px 37px 40px 46px;
}

.documents-container>a {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.documents-table {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.documents-table th, .documents-table td {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #c3c3c3;
}

.documents-table th {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.documents-table.no-text-transform th {
    text-transform: none;
}

.documents-table .info-bubble.info-bubble-bottom.info-bubble-bottom-right
    {
    right: -32px;
}

.document-status {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 14px;
    width: 14px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 100%;
    border-radius: 100%;
}

.document-status--red {
    background: #ed1b2e;
}

.meta {
    color: #9d9d9d;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

JavaScript Code

```
 $('.js-toggle-table-details').on('click', function() {
                var $tablerow = $(this).next('.table-row-details');
                $('.table-row-details').not($tablerow).hide();
                $($tablerow).slideToggle("slow").focus();
            });
```

Comment: Try posting the relevant code in the question. And please also elaborate on  _it's not working_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it's written in the documentation https://api.jquery.com/focus/, only link, input, select or maybe textarea can be focused by this method or you have to use tabIndex attribute as below:

```
 <tr class="with-details js-toggle-table-details" tabIndex = "1">
```

I updated your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E85pn/14/